# GAE cloud endpoint integration with android - GoogleJsonResponseException 404 not found

Tags: android, google-app-engine, cloud, http-status-code-404, endpoint

I have written GAE cloud endpoint APIs and have successfully deployed them to App Engine. The APIs run successfully locally as well as after deployment on App Engine.

After generating cloud endpoints, i tried to call one of the APIs in my Android client and it throws "GoogleJSONResponseException 404 not found" exception. In the API method, I am using HttpURLConnection and  JAXB unmarshaller to call a URL and unmarshall the XML response. The code is as follows:

```
String uri=<some url>;
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyResponse.class);
InputStream xml = connection.getInputStream();
response = (MyResponse) jc.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xml);

connection.disconnect();
```

Why does this not work only when trying to call from the android client using the endpoint client library? Am i doing something wrong?

Note: I called another API in the same android client which just inserts data into the datastore and it works fine

The LogCat console looks as follows:

```
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035): Not Found
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:314)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1060)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:412)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:345)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:463)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.niru.i_collect.RegistrationActivity$FindAddressTask.doInBackground(RegistrationActivity.java:296)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at com.niru.i_collect.RegistrationActivity$FindAddressTask.doInBackground(RegistrationActivity.java:1)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-17 11:44:49.081: W/System.err(2035):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a weird bug in App Engine.  It seems that when this happens, you have to go to the  [App Engine Console](http://appengine.google.com) -> `Main` -> `Versions`.

There you will see a list of versions with a `Make Default` button below.  Select the radio button for the latest version and press the make default button, wait a minute or so, and try your call again.

Note that *even if you have only one version that is already set as the default* this solution should still work.

You may have to do this again the next time you deploy to app engine.

Comment: GREAT WORK THANKS THIS WAS SOOOOOO FRUSTRATING :)

Comment: I tried to redeploy the backend and also tried to "make default" the only version of my backend that existed.  I unfortunately still have the same error.  - Android studio / endpoints / datastore